Reference request: Generate 3-cycles with commutators
I would like to know a reference in the math literature where the Lemma below is proven or at least mentioned, in its full generality and abstract form. Not just as an exercise. I am not asking for a proof (it is easy). Does it perhaps even have a common name?

Lemma. Let $f,g \in S_X$ be two permutations such that there is exactly one element $x \in X$ that is moved by $f$ and $g$. Then the commutator $[f,g] := f^{-1} \circ g^{-1} \circ f \circ g$ is a $3$-cycle, namely $(x ~ f^{-1}(x) ~ g^{-1}(x))$.

Context: This lemma is quite useful to solve all sorts of twisty puzzles.
Related questions:

3-Cycles and Twisty Puzzles
Commutator is a 3-cycle if...


Yes, I saw the question also here. Some literature is listed here.

Erm, yes that was me actually (cube raccoon is my name in the puzzle community). I was looking for a proof in the math literature. I will specify that, gimme a second.

(I was referring to the first version of your comment which only had the first link to reddit.)

In the book Permutation groups by Dixon, Mortimer the following is Exercise 1.6.7 (page 19):

If $x,y \in \mathrm{Sym}(\Omega)$ and $\Gamma := \mathrm{supp}(x) \cap \mathrm{supp}(y)$, show that $\mathrm{supp} [x,y] \subseteq \Gamma \cup \Gamma^x \cup \Gamma^y$. In particular, if $|\Gamma|=1$, show that $[x,y]$ is a $3$-cycle.

I regard this as a partial answer since it is only an exercise in the book.
